# Laravel 4: Getter and Setter Methods

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I tried to get Getter & Setter Methods work (from Laravel 3 in Laravel 4)

but display Error.

is there any work around here?

they are very useful in password case:

```
public function set_password($password)
{
    $this->set_attribute('hashed_password', Hash::make($password));
}
```

http://three.laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent

Comment: How are you calling set_password?

Comment: you don't , when you set new user record with password, Laravel called it for you, just put setPasswordAttribute() in your model  (check my answer below)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just found the answer:

Now it called Accessors & Mutators

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-mutators

to hash password before you set it:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($pass)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($pass);
}
```

Comment: Does exist a classic OOP getters and setters declaration for Eloquent model instead of have a look every time on the related Database table?